# Elasticsearch The best way to compare large texts

Tags: elasticsearch, plagiarism-detection

I have several thousand texts in elasticsearch which I have to compare with text segments and detect plagiarism (complete coincidence). I plan to take several large segments from different parts of the checked texts and find them in documents loaded into elasticsearch. I am trying to find a better way in elasticsearch.

Comment: The [More Like This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query might be useful

Comment: There is a similarity module: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html